# Difference between Category, Rank and Taxon

Tags: terminology, taxonomy, classification

Is there any differences between the terms Category, Rank and Taxon or they all are same?

I remember an explanation which goes on like this:

Category and Rank are the same and are the categories of taxonomic heirarchy whereas taxons are the organisms present in those.

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe adding some example context would help answer. Anyway, a taxon is not an organism, but rather any level and grouping one can distinguiah, the last smallest one being a species (a group of individuals). Of the other two, no idea to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

A **[taxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxon)** (plural taxa) is any taxonomic unit. For example, the class Mammalia is a taxon which includes all mammalian species. Similarly, a species is a taxon, *Panthera tigris* being the tiger. This taxon contains lower taxa, which are sub-species, such as *Panthera tigris tigris* (Bengal tiger) or *Panthera tigris sumatrae* (Sumatran tiger).

**[Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank)** is simply the level of a taxon in the taxonomic heirarchy. For example, the taxa Mammalia and Aves both have the same rank since they are both classes. *Panthera tigris sumatrae* is of a lower rank than *Panthera tigris* because the former is a sub-species and the latter a species. Use of the term rank is only truly meaningful when comparing two taxa.

Taxonomic **category** is usually – for better or worse – used interchangeably with the term taxonomic rank. [A Dictionary of Biology (6 ed.)](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199204625.001.0001/acref-9780199204625-e-3760) certainly indicates that the terms rank and category are equivalent. The major taxonomic categories are domain, kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, genus, and species. A category can contain one or more taxa.

Another example, to summarize:

- Carnivora is a taxon, which contains many species including *Vulpes
  vulpes* (red fox)
- Carnivora is in the category of order
- Carnivora (order) is a higher rank than *Vulpes vulpes* (species)

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Great answer, but adding a reference or two would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if Reptilia is considered a taxon. It is most definitely not a clade.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Yes, it was a bad example - I've changed it

Comment: @HarryVervet Please correct me if I am wrong -- you said `"the taxa Mammalia and Aves both have the same rank since they are both classes"`... which would that imply that `class` is the name of their shared rank, and thus `kingdom, phylum, etc` refer to taxonomy ranks, and are not taxons themselves